How to typecase an object while also parsing a string within object?
I have a custom defined Model:
class Person {
    age: number;
    personality: Personality;
}

class Personality {
    shy: boolean;
    moody: boolean;
}

When I fetch result from API, I receive:
{
    age: 20;
    personality: "\{\"shy\": \"true\",\"moody\":\"false\"\}"
}

I assign API response to a variable using:
response.body().personality = JSON.parse(response.body().personality)
const person = response.body() as Person

Here personality is string which I need to be parsed directly.
How can I avoid this statement : response.body().personality = JSON.parse(response.body().personality)

If you want to parse the value, why do you want to avoid parsing the value?  Is your code not working in some way?

• Please [edit] the code to be a [mre] that either defines response or, ideally, replaces it with something else. Right now the fact that apparently body is a function that needs to be called is distracting at best, since it's not clear that you get the same object every time. • Please [edit] to clarify exactly why you want to "avoid" the statement and in what way. It's not really plausible to avoid parsing if you get a string. That code has to go somewhere. But maybe you just mean you want to avoid calling response.body too many times? Not sure. Please [edit] to clarify.

@David I want to parse the value, but I want that to happen automatically inside Personality Class.

You can create a constructor in your Person class that will handle the parsing of the personality field. This way, whenever you create a new Person object, the personality field will be automatically parsed from a string to a Personality object.
class Personality {
    shy: boolean;
    moody: boolean;

    constructor(data: any) {
        this.shy = data.shy === 'true';
        this.moody = data.moody === 'true';
    }
}

class Person {
    age: number;
    personality: Personality;

    constructor(data: any) {
        this.age = data.age;
        this.personality = new Personality(JSON.parse(data.personality));
    }
}

Now, when you receive the response from the API, you can create a new Person object like this:
const person = new Person(response.body());

This will automatically parse the personality field from a string to a Personality object.
